# Why am I getting django.db.models error telling me I have no attribute for TextChoices in Django (3.1.6) and Python(3.8)?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

thanks so much for reading. I've  got this running on my computer no problem. It's working on my VS on Windows 10. But this error keeps coming up, it looks like TextChoices is no longer usable?

AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'TextChoices'

I'm putting it u0p on PythonAnywhere, Python 3.8, and Django 3.1.6
I am still new at this, so please forgive me1

My issue is with the TextChoices, here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sandorf/project/listings/models.py", line 6, in <module>
class Listings(models.Model):
File "/home/sandorf/project/listings/models.py", line 7, in Listings
class Country(models.TextChoices):
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'TextChoices'
```

This is my models.py in the app directory

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.

 class Listings(models.Model):
    class Country(models.TextChoices):
        USA = "USA"
        CHINA = "China"
        CANADA = "Canada"
        INDIA = "India"
        UK = "UK"
        EUROPE = "Europe"
     MIDDLE_EAST = "Middle East"
     OTHER = "Other"

    class Topic(models.TextChoices):
        STATISTICS = "Statistics"
        VACCINE = "Vaccine"
        NEW_STRAINS = "New Strains"
        LOCKDOWN = "Lockdown"
        COVID_NEWS = "Covid News"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=745)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=745)
    summary = models.TextField(Null=False)
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=Country.choices,
        default="Country.OTHER")
    topic = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=Topic.choices,
        default="Topic.COVID_NEWS")
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    photo_1 = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/) this way:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.

 class Listings(models.Model):

    COUNTRIES = (
        ('US', 'United States of America'),
        ('CH', 'China'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=745)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=COUNTRIES, default='US')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Thank you Hofman, worked on the first try. Much appreciated!